# Given a string whenever you see the word "ant" substitute into the string the word "termite"

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, substring

I'm trying to substitute all "ant" words on blow text to "termite" without using replace function. I can only replace the first word on the text. Can somebody show me what I did wrong in my loop? Thank you!
 P.s. Also this is an assignment from school. I have to code it in certain way as a required from my professor.

```
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void HomeworkHeader();

 string Text = "Auntie saw an ant cross the kitchen counter. Then latter she 
 saw a group of ants cross the floor. But, she was focused on adding a new 2 
 meter antenna to her 40 foot antenna mast. Friends would be coming over to 
 help with the raising and lowering of the antenna mast.";

 string FindAndSubstitutes(string bText, string OldWord, string NewWord);

 int main()
 {
      HomeworkHeader();
      cout << Text << endl;
      cout << endl;
      string Revise = FindAndSubstitutes(Text, "ant", "termite");
      cout << Revise;
      return 0;
  }

  string FindAndSubstitutes(string bText, string OldWord, string 
     NewWord)
  {
   int len = Text.length();
    int OldStrLen = OldWord.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int WhereIsAnt = Text.find(OldWord);
        string partBefore = Text.substr(0, WhereIsAnt);
        string partAfter = Text.substr( WhereIsAnt + OldStrLen + 1);
        bText = partBefore + NewWord + partAfter;

     }

     return bText;
     }
```

Comment: Take a close look at what variables you use in the `FindAndSubstitutes` function. I suggest you start by making `Text` a *local* variable inside the `main` function.

Comment: You want to use find(str, pos ) so that you search for the text from a position in the string.,otherwise you will always be searching from the beginning of the string. Also when you fix that, you will need to build up bText rather than reassigning it every time.

Comment: Do you actually want _antenna_ changed to _termiteena_ ???

Answer (score 1):

You need loop till you won't find any occurences of OldWord and keep copying substrings to replace with NewWord, as you already did. Cheers, hope it helps.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void HomeworkHeader();

string Text = "Auntie saw an ant cross the kitchen counter. Then latter she \
saw a group of ants cross the floor. But, she was focused on adding a new 2 \
meter antenna to her 40 foot antenna mast. Friends would be coming over to \
help with the raising and lowering of the antenna mast.";

string FindAndSubstitutes(string bText, string OldWord, string NewWord);

int main()
{
    HomeworkHeader();
    cout << Text << endl;
    cout << endl;
    string Revise = FindAndSubstitutes(Text, "ant", "termite");
    cout << Revise;
    return 0;
}

string FindAndSubstitutes(string Text, string OldWord, string NewWord)
{
    int len = Text.length();
    int OldStrLen = OldWord.length();
    int WhereIsAnt;

    while( (WhereIsAnt = Text.find(OldWord)) >= 0 )
    {
        string partBefore = Text.substr(0, WhereIsAnt);
        string partAfter = Text.substr( WhereIsAnt + OldStrLen);
        Text = partBefore + NewWord + partAfter;
    }

    return Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There some points for you to consider, you used `Text` (the global variable) instead of `bText` the argument, and then you loop with size of the string but instead it should loop while there is nothing to replace.
and the most important point to consider in your algorithm is each time you searched from the beginning instead of the last found position.

```html
<iframe height="477px" width="100%" src="https://repl.it/repls/RudeLinedGzip?lite=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-modals"></iframe>
```

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


string Text = "Auntie saw an ant cross the kitchen counter. Then latter she\ 
saw a group of ants cross the floor. But, she was focused on adding a new 2 \
meter antenna to her 40 foot antenna mast. Friends would be coming over to \
help with the raising and lowering of the antenna mast.";

string FindAndSubstitutes(string bText, string OldWord, string NewWord);

int main()
{
      cout << Text << endl;
      cout << endl;
      string Revise = FindAndSubstitutes(Text, "ant", "termite");
      cout << Revise << endl;
      return 0;
}

string FindAndSubstitutes(string bText, string OldWord, string NewWord)
{
  int len = Text.length();
  int OldStrLen = OldWord.length();
  size_t WhereIsAnt = bText.find(OldWord, 0);
  while(WhereIsAnt != string::npos)
  {
      string partBefore = bText.substr(0, WhereIsAnt);
      string partAfter = bText.substr( WhereIsAnt + OldStrLen );
      bText = partBefore + NewWord + partAfter;
      WhereIsAnt = bText.find(OldWord,WhereIsAnt+1);
  }
  return bText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the text you used as example, you can do it with two calls to find and replace functions (for fixed patterns), just search for `" ants "` and replace it with `" termites "`, then search for `" ant "`, then replace all ocurrences with `" termite "`.  This way you'll not lead to changing `"antenna"` with `"termiteenna"`, as you have several cases.

If you dig a little wiht regular expressions and the related libraries, you can get a better approach, that allows `ant` or `ants` to be stuck to punctuation characters (like `,`,  `.` or `?`) so, the substitution works also for these.  See `regex(3)` library documentation.